# issue in laravel with returning query

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get `blockid` out of `blocksobject`,  if i do:

```
return $blocksobject
```

My output is:

```
[{"userid":5,"objectid":25,"id":25,"blockid":3},
{"userid":5,"objectid":26,"id":26,"blockid":3},
{"userid":5,"objectid":28,"id":28,"blockid":4}]
```

Code:

```
    $blocksobject = ObjectAccess::select('objectsaccess.userid', 'objectsaccess.objectid', 'objects.id', 'objects.blockid')
            ->where('objectsaccess.userid', Auth::user()->id)

            ->join('objects', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectsaccess.objectid')



            ->get();
```

But if i:

```
return $blocksobject->blockid;
```

I get following error:

> Property [objectid] does not exist on this collection instance.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

EDIT1: BLADE

```
    @foreach($blocksobject as $blockk->where($block->id,'=','objects.blockid')->first())

        $blockids[] = $block->blockid;
        @endforeach
```

$block->id works in the blade, it giveso ut the current id, so i just want to get the items that match the current id. 
Gives out error of : Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: Okay firstly you need to do most of your logic in your controller, so I would run your query and then return your blockids array to your view. Then you can use your foreach in the blade and apply an if statement inside

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have multiple block id's.

If you want to get each result individually you could do the following which will return an array of your blockids

```
$blocksobject = ObjectAccess::select('objectsaccess.userid', 'objectsaccess.objectid', 'objects.id', 'objects.blockid')
            ->where('objectsaccess.userid', Auth::user()->id)   
            ->join('objects', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectsaccess.objectid')
            ->get();

$blockids = [];

foreach($blocksobject as $block) {
    $blockids[] = $block->blockid;
}

return $blockids;
```

If you wanted to return the first result in your query you can do the following

```
$blocksobject = ObjectAccess::select('objectsaccess.userid', 'objectsaccess.objectid', 'objects.id', 'objects.blockid')
            ->where('objectsaccess.userid', Auth::user()->id)   
            ->join('objects', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectsaccess.objectid')
            ->first();

return $blocksobject;
```

The first method will return one object whereas the get method returns a collection of results

Comment: ok great, i applied it to the blade as such, but gives me error of   :  Can't use method return value in write context                                                                              here is code :                                             @foreach($blocksobject as $blockk->where($block->id,'=','blockid')->first())

   $blockids[] = $block->blockid;
   @endforeach

Comment: Can you show me your blade template and what code is not working by adding it to your question

Comment: done, rest of template is ok, just when i added that line. edited main post

Answer (score 0):

This will give all records of the current user that have `objects.blockid = 3`.

```
 $blocksobject = ObjectAccess::select('objectsaccess.userid', 'objectsaccess.objectid', 'objects.id', 'objects.blockid')
                ->where(['objectsaccess.userid' => Auth::user()->id , 'objects.blockid' => '3' ])
                ->join('objects', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectsaccess.objectid')
                ->get();
```

And if you return `$blocksobject->blockid;` there is no wonder it gives you an error as `$blocksobject` is a multidimensional array not an array.

You should just return this: `return $blocksobject;` and handle what you want to show in a foreach loop in your view.

> For example to get the userid and blockid of each record:

```
  @foreach($blocksobject as $singleobject)
         <div> {{   $singleobject->userid; }}</div>
         <div> {{  $singleobject->blockid; }}</div>  
   @endforeach
```

Comment: what if i want it to show the 2 records that has blockid : 3 ? and do it in blade ?  @foreach($blocksobject as $blockk->where($block->id,'=','blockid')->first())

   $blockids[] = $block->blockid;
   @endforeach

Comment: use this `->take(2)->get();` instead of this  `->get();` at the end of the query

Comment: but not only show 2 records, but to show the records that has blockid: 3 . in this case was just 2. but it can be many

Comment: im using it in blade,  $block->id works in blade, and i used         @foreach($blocksobject as $blockk->where($block->id,'=','objects.blockid')->first())

Comment: get error Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: you cant return an array in the conditions of a for-each loop. what do you wan to display?

Comment: i want to display the numbers of items that match the query, in this case 2

Comment: if you want to show the number 2. just do this inside your blade and no foreach needed `{{count($blocksobject)}}` , if you want something else just say exactly what you want.